# Why does not display ckeditor?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I use a standart pack.

There is JS code with a name **text**:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                CKEDITOR.replace( 'text', {
                    toolbar: [
                        { name: 'document', items: [ 'Source', '-', 'NewPage', 'Preview', '-', 'Templates' ] }, // Defines toolbar group with name (used to create voice label) and items in 3 subgroups.
                        [ 'Cut', 'Copy', 'Paste', 'PasteText', 'PasteFromWord', '-', 'Undo', 'Redo' ],          // Defines toolbar group without name.
                        '/',                                                                                    // Line break - next group will be placed in new line.
                        { name: 'basicstyles', items: [ 'Bold', 'Italic' ] }
                    ]
                });
            </script>
```

I get error in console Chrome:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of undefined
```

**HTML Code:**

```
<div class="text"><textarea name="text" placeholder="Основной текст..."></textarea></div>
```

Comment: you should post the HTML as well.

Comment: I get HTML from via AJAX

Comment: We need to see a sample, because it's very hard to guess what may be wrong. This error says nothing.

Answer (score 0):

In the past similar errors were sometime related to missing / broken language file. Clear the browser cache and load CKEditor again. If it does not help check the network tab in your browser and see if the language file is being loaded properly.